# production build failed in Angular v5 project >> global CLI version is 6.x

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli-v6

I am trying to build my angular app for production. I am getting error `ERROR in Either route or analyzedModules has to be specified` . I have searched for the solutions and they all suggesting to downgrade CLI version but I don't want to downgrade my CLI version.

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.7
Node: 8.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.7
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.7
@angular/cli                      6.2.7
@angular/compiler-cli             6.1.10
@angular/language-service         6.1.10
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.7
@schematics/angular               0.8.7
@schematics/update                0.8.7
rxjs                              5.5.12
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.16.4`
`
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DattatrayDongane It's look like you are missing route setup or import in your module file

Comment: It doesn't seem that issue with my routing. here is my import section. `imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule ,
 HttpClientModule,
 NotifierModule.withConfig(customNotifierOptions),
 Ng2SmartTableModule,
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
 
  ],`

Comment: Also want to mention that project is getting build without `--prod`. issue is when I build it for production.

Comment: reverted the version of the Compiler CLI to 5.2.11 with  Angular 5.2.